# The cv::Mat image finished with exit code 11 when multiply with pixel value with int

Tags: image, opencv, exit-code

I am trying to multiply the index of the image with image pixel value intensity by two for loops. but sometimes the code was interrupted early with " finished with exit code 11" error after some loop.
PS, I use Mac with Clion IDE, can someone help me!!!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cmath>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <Eigen/Geometry>

int main(int argc,char** argv){
vector<cv::Point2d> Orientation(vector<cv::KeyPoint>& ,cv::Mat & );
std::string Img_dir="/Users/mars_zhang/Downloads/A/1.png";
cv::Mat ImgCOLOR,Img,Imgout,Test;
Img=cv::imread(Img_dir,0);
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> Keypoints;

cv::Ptr<cv::FastFeatureDetector> Feature_Detector=cv::FastFeatureDetector::create(160) ;

Feature_Detector->detect(Img,Keypoints);
cv::drawKeypoints(Img,Keypoints,Imgout);
std::cout<< Img.size<<std::endl;
vector<cv::Point2d> Coordination;
Coordination=Orientation(Keypoints,Img);
cout<< Coordination[0]<<endl;
cout<<"The Img type is = " << Img.type() << endl;

}



vector<cv::Point2d> Orientation(vector<cv::KeyPoint> &Keypoints,cv::Mat & Img)
{
int Xbound,Ybound,X,Y;
Ybound = Img.rows - 8;
Xbound = Img.cols - 8;
vector<cv::Point2d> Coordination;
cout<<"Find "<< Keypoints.size()<<"  Keypoints"<<endl;
for (auto &kp :Keypoints){
    X = kp.pt.x,
    Y = kp.pt.y;
    cv::Point Point;

    if ((8 < X < Xbound) & (8 < Y < Ybound)) {

        int m10 = 0, m01 = 0, m00 = 0 ,pixel;

        for (int x_idx = X - 7; x_idx < X + 7; x_idx++)
        {
            for (int y_idx = Y - 7; y_idx < Y + 7; y_idx++)
            {
                pixel=(int)Img.at<uchar>(x_idx, y_idx);
                cout<<"The pixel at "<<x_idx<<"  "<<y_idx<<"==="<<pixel<<endl;

                    Point.x += x_idx * pixel;
                    Point.y += y_idx * pixel;
                    m00 += pixel;
             }
         }
        Coordination.push_back(Point/m00);
     }
  }
 return Coordination;
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int X=10;
int Xbound=2;
std::cout << (8 < X < Xbound) << "!\n";
```

will give you 1 .

(8 < 10)=true=1
and 1 < 2

dont combine conditions this way, use (8 < X && X < Xbound).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but after I correct this the error still exists.

Comment: Also you need to check if Coordination is not empty, but trying to access its element: cout<< Coordination[0]<<endl;

Comment: Also not pixel=(int)Img.at<uchar>(x_idx, y_idx);
but pixel=(int)Img.at<uchar>(y_idx,x_idx);

Comment: Thank you so much, I miss the Coordination order.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what [Andrey Smorodov answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63159507/2405914), there is one other issue on the if statement below

```
if ((8 < X < Xbound) & (8 < Y < Ybound))
```

The and operator is `&&`. `&` is another kind of operator, I'm pretty sure you didn't want to use it here...

Comment: Thanks for your help, but after I correct this the error still exists.